# How do i do a 2nd sort in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart, `mylist.sort((a,b) => a.mydate.compareTo(b.mydate))` will sort my list by `mydate` in ascending order.

How do i sort by `a.quantity` also?

In c#, i would use `thenby` to first sort by date, then by quantity.

Comment: do it twice?
mylist.sort((a,b) => a.mydate.compareTo(b.mydate));
mylist.sort((a,b) => a.quantity.compareTo(b.quantity));

Comment: if i do it that way, it would just sort it by quantity and bypass the mydate. i need it by mydate then by quantity. in c# you would use the thenby method.

Comment: @IqanShaikh No, `Iterable.sort` is not a stable sort, so that would not work.  You would need to use `mergeSort` from `package:collection` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find anything out of the box.
But a workaround by implementing a `compareTo` method in your class

```dart
class someclass {
  int quantity;
  DateTime mydate;
  
  someclass({this.quantity, this.mydate});
  
  int compareTo(someclass second) {
    int res = mydate.compareTo(second.mydate);
    if (res == 0) {
     return quantity.compareTo(second.quantity); 
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

and then `x.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));`

https://gist.github.com/iqans/6cc01ceda5b318714a44e135a8876cb6

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can `implements Comparable` and call `sort`

code snippet

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
  String name;
  DateTime mydate;
  int quantity;

  Item({this.name, this.mydate, this.quantity});

  @override
  int compareTo(Item other) {
    int dateDiff = mydate.compareTo(other.mydate);

    return dateDiff != 0 ? dateDiff : this.quantity.compareTo(other.quantity);
  }
}

List<Item> items = [
     ...
    ];

items.sort();

items.forEach((Item item) {
  print(
      '${item.name} - ${item.mydate.toIso8601String()} - ${item.quantity}');
});
```

output

```
I/flutter (19496): c - 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000 - 4
I/flutter (19496): a - 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000 - 5
I/flutter (19496): d - 2020-02-01T00:00:00.000 - 3
I/flutter (19496): b - 2020-02-01T00:00:00.000 - 10
I/flutter (19496): e - 2020-03-01T00:00:00.000 - 3
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
  String name;
  DateTime mydate;
  int quantity;

  Item({this.name, this.mydate, this.quantity});

  @override
  int compareTo(Item other) {
    int dateDiff = mydate.compareTo(other.mydate);

    return dateDiff != 0 ? dateDiff : this.quantity.compareTo(other.quantity);
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    List<Item> items = [
      Item(
          name: "e",
          mydate: DateTime.parse("2020-03-01 00:00:00"),
          quantity: 3),
      Item(
          name: "a",
          mydate: DateTime.parse("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
          quantity: 5),
      Item(
          name: "b",
          mydate: DateTime.parse("2020-02-01 00:00:00"),
          quantity: 10),
      Item(
          name: "c",
          mydate: DateTime.parse("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
          quantity: 4),
      Item(
          name: "d",
          mydate: DateTime.parse("2020-02-01 00:00:00"),
          quantity: 3),
    ];

    items.sort();

    items.forEach((Item item) {
      print(
          '${item.name} - ${item.mydate.toIso8601String()} - ${item.quantity}');
    });

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Multi_Sort package in pub.dev and worked great

Comment: Please, put an code example to make this answer more clear.